# If $A ∈M_n(C)$ is such that $(Ax,x) = 0$ for all $x ∈C^n$, then $A = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Which of the following statements are true?

$1.$ If $A ∈M_n(C)$ is such that $(Ax,x) = 0$ for all $x ∈C^n$, then $A = 0$.

$2.$ If $A ∈M_n(C)$ is such that $(Ax,x) ≥ 0$ for all $x ∈C^n$, then $A = A^∗$.

I know that $A$ is skew symmetric Matrix iff $x^tAx = 0$ for all $x ∈R^n$ and $A ∈M_n(R)$.

The question posted by Neha Gupta had an WRONG answer. That's why I posted it again.

Comment: $C^n$ @DietrichBurde

Comment: You mean $\mathbb{C}^n$...

Comment: Yes@DietrichBurde

Comment: possible duplicate  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2707119/which-of-the-following-statements-are-true-here-cn-is-complex-field

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which of the following statements are true? here $C^n$ is complex field.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2707119/which-of-the-following-statements-are-true-here-cn-is-complex-field)

Comment: Answer of your question was wrong.@Nehagupta

Comment: @cmi   Question to maine upload kiya phele,,,,wasie  tumne  copy  and paste ki hai meri   question  ko..

Comment: @sani can u  show  ur work ???   how can u claim that  that was wrong

Comment: Tum Uska uttor accept kiya iska matlab tume samajh me ageya uska uttor.. Now Can you please write an answer here. I will accept your answer if it is acceptable.@Nehagupta

Comment: option  b)  and c)   will  be true .....as  for b ) $$A+A^*=0$$
$$A-A^*=0$$ and  option C to  clearly dikh rhi hai,,,

Comment: Chup gayii kiu?@Nehagupta

Answer (score 5):

Both are true. For the first one, the canonical way is to use the Polarization identity to show that $(Ax,y)=0$ for all $x,y$. A less standard way is to notice that $[x,y]=(Ax,y)$ is a sesquilinear form (since $[x,x]=(Ax,x)=0\geq0$), so one has, using Cauchy-Schwarz for $[\cdot,\cdot]$, 
$$
\|Ax\|^2=(Ax,Ax)=[x,Ax]\leq [x,x]^{1/2}[Ax,Ax]^{1/2}=(Ax,x)^{1/2}(A^2x,Ax)^{1/2}=0.
$$
Thus $Ax=0$ for all $x$.

For the second one, 
$$
(A^*x,x)=(x,Ax)=\overline{(Ax,x)}=(Ax,x). 
$$
So $((A^*-A)x,x)=0$ for all $x$.

Comment: Where did u use the fact that the Matrix and the column vectors are in Complex field?@Martin Argerami

Comment: In a real vector space $(Ax,x)\geq0$ for all $x$ is not enough to make $A$ positive, and then you cannot conclude that the form $[x,y]:=(Ax,y)$ satisfies Cauchy-Schwarz, nor one can use Polarization.

Comment: What do you mean by Positive $A$?@Martin Argerami

Comment: I really did not understand what you are trying to say.@Martin Argerami

Comment: I am waiting for your explanation. I hope you would elaborate to make it understandable.@Martin Argerami

Comment: First of all $(x,y) = (Ax, y)$ can not be an inner-product as $(x,x)$ is always zero. Can you please correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: I never said "inner product". I said "sesquilinear form".

Comment: I did not know sesquilinear form. I am reading about it.@MartinArgerami

Comment: I really can not understand...Can you please elaborate little bit?@MartinArgerami

Comment: I am waiting for your explanation@MartinArgerami  Please help me to understand. I am looking forward to your reply.

Answer (score 1):

Statement $1$ is true as $(A(x+y),x+y))=0$ gives us $(Ax,y)+(Ay,x)=0$ and $(A(x+iy),x+iy)$ gives us $(Ax,y)-(Ay,x)=0$.
Statement $2$ is also true but I am satisfied with Martin's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Some insight into the problems via the *field (of values) of $A$* (also called the *numerical range of $A$*).

Given $A \in M_n(\mathbb{C})$, the *field (of values) of $A$*, denoted by $F(A)$, is defined by
$$
F(A) = \{ z^*Az\mid z^*z=1\}.
$$ 
It is well-known that this set is a compact, convex subset of $\mathbb{C}$ that contains the spectrum of $A$. It is also known, and otherwise easy to establish, that $F(A) = \alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ if and only if $A = \alpha I$. This establishes (1).

Let 
$$H(A):=(A+A^*)/2$$ and 
$$S(A) :=(A-A^*)/2.$$ 
Notice that $A = H(A) + S(A)$ and that $H(A)$ and $iS(A)$ are both Hermitian.

It is known that $F(H(A)) = \text{Re}(F(A))$ and $F(S(A)) = \text{Im}(F(A))$. Thus, if $\langle Ax,x\rangle \ge 0$ for any $x\in \mathbb{C}^n$, then $F(S(A)) = \text{Im}(F(A)) = \{0\}$. Following (1), $S(A) = 0$, i.e., $A = A^*$.